# getting error while running chroot comand

Tags: linux, shell

As a root user am ensuring that the permission for my application insights are owned by insights user and not root.

But getting following error:

```
chroot insights:insights /home/insights/* -R    
chroot: cannot change root directory to : no such file or directory centos
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using the wrong command to change the ownership of the directory. Please use the `chown` command instead of `chroot`.